# Best way to transfer data from on-prem to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, migration

I have a requirement to transfer data(one time) from on prem to AWS S3. The data size is around 1 TB. I was going through AWS Datasync,  Snowball etc...  But these managed services are better to migrate if the data is in petabytes.  Can someone suggest me the best way to transfer the data in a secured way cost effectively

Comment: where does the data need to end up?  S3?  Database? (based on the tags I guess S3) which timeframe do you have for the transfer?

Comment: I need to store it in S3. Timings are not a constraint

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). This command will copy data to Amazon S3:

```
aws s3 sync c:/MyDir s3://my-bucket/
```

If there is a network failure or timeout, simply run the command again. It only copies files that are not already present in the destination.

The time taken will depend upon the speed of your Internet connection.

You could also consider using **AWS Snowball**, which is a piece of hardware that is sent to your location. It can hold 50TB of data and costs $200.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no specific requirements (apart from the fact that it needs to be encrypted and the file-size is 1TB) then I would suggest you stick to something plain and simple.  S3 supports an object size of 5TB so you wouldn't run into trouble.  I don't know if your data is made up of many smaller files or 1 big file (or zip) but in essence its all the same.  Since the end-points or all encrypted you should be fine (if your worried, you can encrypt your files before and they will be encrypted while stored (if its backup of something).  To get to the point, you can use API tools for transfer or just file-explorer type of tools which have also connectivity to S3 (e.g. https://www.cloudberrylab.com/explorer/amazon-s3.aspx).  some other point:  cost-effectiviness of storage/transfer all depends on how frequent you need the data, if just a backup or just in case.  archiving to glacier is much cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

1 TB is large but it's not so large that it'll take you weeks to get your data onto S3. However if you don't have a good upload speed, use **Snowball**.

https://aws.amazon.com/snowball/

Snowball is a device shipped to you which can hold up to 100TB. You load your data onto it and ship it back to AWS and they'll upload it to the S3 bucket you specify when loading the data.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in multiple ways.

1. Using AWS Cli, we can copy files from local to S3
2. AWS Transfer  using FTP or SFTP (AWS SFTP)

Please [refer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83Wa4RJuMwo)

3. There are tools like cloudberry clients which has a UI interface
4. You can use AWS DataSync Tool

Comment: Can you share some documentation or reference links to know how to pull data from an external on-premises server to AWS S3 using AWS Transfer Family? I'm searching on Internet from last couple of days but can't find a proper doc. This doc doesn't have proper info https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/moving-external-site-data-to-aws-for-file-transfers-with-aws-transfer-family/